# The 3 cards riddle (from MindYourDecisions)

Tags: probability

[3 cards riddle](https://youtu.be/1IFM1ngwEb0)
I just want to know if there's an error to this explanation, and if so what it was.

The **end goal** is to show that the probability of seeing a blue side when you turn it over is actually     **2/3, instead of 1/2.**

*

*

*

One was this,
cards given :RED-RED, BLUE-BLUE, RED-BLUE

P(Opposite side being blue|This side is blue) = P(Opposite side is blue and this side is blue)/P(This side is blue)

Now P(Opposite side is blue and this side is blue) is obvious the same as P(Both sides are blue) and there is only one card like that out of 3 and so the probability is 1/3.

P(This side is blue) is 1/2 because there are equal numbers of red sides and blue sides.

So lets plug those both into the formula and we get: P(Opposite side being blue|This side is blue) = (1/3)/(1/2) = 2/3
QED

Alternatively you might want to exclude the red-red card altogether, in which case you get P(Opposite side being blue|This side is blue) = (1/2)/(3/4) = 2/3.

*

*

*

**HOWEVER**, by the same logic, in order to turn over and see the blue side

Cards given: GREEN-BlUE, GREEN-RED

=P(Opposite side is blue | This side is green)

=P(one side blue and one side green) / P(This side is green)

=(1/2) / (2/4)

**=1 ????**

Comment: Yes, there is.  Are you sure that's all you want to know?

Comment: im editting it right now, because i wrongly worded it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if there is an error with my calculation, if you happen to not understand, the linked video will help

Comment: Both approaches are correct.  You could also say that there are 3 blue faces.  And 2 of the blue faces have a blue opposite face.

Comment: I checked with a different calculation, and it seems that it does not work then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is using P(one side blue and one side green) as the numerator. The right numerator is P(opposite side blue and this side green), which is 1/4. This produces the correct answer: (1/4)/(1/2)=1/2.

In the original version, P(opposite side blue and this side blue) is equal to P(both sides blue) because with a card that is blue on both sides, either way you will have the opposite side blue and this side blue. But with a card that is blue and green, you can have the opposite side blue or the opposite side green, so P(one side blue and one side green) and P(opposite side blue and this side green) are not equal.

Comment: This is quite helpful but could you explain how you got 1/4?

Comment: @user352935 The probability of a blue/green card is 1/2. Given that card, 1/2 the time the blue side will be up and 1/2 the time the green side will be up. So it is 1/2*1/2=1/4 overall to have green up and blue down.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. thanks for the help